# How to send digits while making outgoing phone call with TWILIO

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I am using Twilio to make outgoing call to a number that is running an IVR system and I have to supply various digits as per the required IVR menu options. Right now, I have tried almost all the sample codes and Quick Start tutorials but it didn't work for me.

I am using ASP .Net web application to make a call using Twilio official C# helper library. I am using following code to make a call.

Following is the TwiML instruction provided to Twilio after the call gets connected

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
        sb.Append("   <Response>");
        sb.Append("         <Dial callerId='+1852xxxxxxx' record='true' >");
        sb.Append("               +1475xxxxxxx ");
        sb.Append("         </Dial>");
        sb.Append("   </Response>");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Please note that the 'Dial' verb doesn't support the sendDigits parameter.

Your immediate response will be highly appreciated, as I am stuck and need to fix this as earliest as possible.

Comment: Are you receiving any responses from Twilio? Any error messages that may help the investigation?

Comment: Have you looked at the Twilio debug console within your account page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thoroughly review the documentation, I found a `<Number>` noun for the `<Dial>` verb that allows to provide `sendDigits` parameter. So my problem has been solved. Thanks to all of you for your support.

Regards,

Tahir Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to pass the `SendDigits` optional parameter along with your outbound API call.

For more information, see this [list of optional parameters when making a Twilio API call](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional)

Comment: I have already reviewed all the available documentation and didn't find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you

```
const call = Device.connect(params);
call.sendDegits("1");
```